# Eclipse Oxygen Oracle java 8

Tags: java, eclipse

Can't install Eclipse Oxygen, I installed Java Oracle 8 following these instructions

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

then I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen , I run the eclipse-inst and I get this :

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=11
/usr/bin/java
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
-name Eclipse Installer
--launcher.library /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133/eclipse_1624.so
-startup /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 358010
-data @noDefault
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

I searched about it and thought it was a location problem, output from

```
which java
/usr/bin/java

whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Here is the content of the eclipse-isnt.ini file :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
--launcher.appendVmargs
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-name
Eclipse Installer
-data
@noDefault
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
```

I already tried to add this line :

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
```

right before -vmargs line, and it still doesn't work.
I get this error code :

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=11
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
-name Eclipse Installer
--launcher.library /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133/eclipse_1624.so
-startup /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 3c8013
-data @noDefault
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/ly/Ly-Data/Linux Programs/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after toying around with the eclipse-inst.ini file i find the porblem and  solved it. all i had to do was to delete the number 2 on one of the ini file lines (which was, for whatever reason always fixing the jvm location to usr/bin/java), so just replace the content of eclipse-inst.ini file with this one :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
--launcher.appendVmargs
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-name
Eclipse Installer
-data
@noDefault
--launcher.GTK_version

-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
```

replace the path in the line beginning with "-vm ..." with your path to java (which you can know by typing the "whereis java" command line).